# Algunos elementos que hacen que Java no sea multiplataforma y cómo evitarlos

Tags: java

Como ya sabemos, uno de los mayores atractivos de Java es que sea multiplataforma. Es decir, funciona en cualquier sistema, ya que quien se encarga de interpretar el código Java es la JVM (Java Virtual Machine).

**Pero** hay pequeños elementos que sirven de tropiezo a esta realidad tan atractiva.

Por ejemplo este código en realidad no es *multiplataforma*:

```
System.out.println("Hola Mundo\n");
```

Ese código no funcionará igual en Windows o en Unix.

**¿Cómo mejorar en ese sentido mi código Java para que funcione igual en todas las plataformas?**

Nota: Esta es una pregunta con auto-respuesta que será marcada como Wiki de comunidad, con la idea de que la respuesta sea editada, indicando todos los detalles posibles a tomar en cuenta para escribir código realmente multiplataforma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay elementos que cambian según los sistemas operativos, y dichos elementos en efecto pueden hacer que nuestro código Java no sea del todo *multiplataforma*.

Podemos enumerarlos en esta respuesta, indicando soluciones que existen, e indicando a partir de qué versión de Java los podemos usar.

### 1. El salto de línea

**Problema:** En Unix es `\n` y en Microsoft Windows es `\r\n`

**Solución:** [`lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator())

**A partir de:** Java 7

**Ejemplo:** `System.out.println("Hola"+System.lineSeparator()+"mundo");`

---

### 2. El separador de nombres de archivos

**Problema:** En Unix y Mac OS es `/` y en Windows es `\`

**Solución:** Obtener el separador de archivos propio del sistema en una variable mediante [`File.separator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) o mediante [`System.getProperty("file.separator")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) y usarla para construir las rutas:

```
String fs = File.separator;
String rutaArchivo = "directorio"+fs+"archivo.txt";
```

---

### 3. El separador de rutas

**Problema:** En Unix y Mac OS es `:` y en Windows es `;`

**Solución:** Obtener el separador de archivos propio del sistema en una variable  y usarla para construir las rutas.

Se puede hacer de tres formas distintas, mediante:

```
pathSeparator = System.getProperty( "path.separator" );
```

O bien:

```
pathSeparator = File.pathSeparator;
```

O bien:

```
char pathSeparatorChar = File.pathSeparatorChar;
```

---

### 4. El directorio root o home

**Problema:** En Unix generalmente es `/` y en Windows `C:\` . Y aparte de eso, puede ser cualquier otra ubicación...

**Solución:** Obtener el directorio raíz mediante la propiedad `user.home` de la clase `System`:

```
File home = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

## 5. El sonido `beep`

**Problema:** La representación Unicode del sonido `beep` es esta: `\007`. Podríamos intentar emitir un beep mediante este código:

```
    System.out.println("\007");
```

Pero el algunos sistemas no funcionará.

Otra opción sería:

```
    System.out.println("beep");
```

**Solución:** [`getDefaultToolkit().beep()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#beep--) funcionará en cualquier sistema.

**A partir de:** JDK 1.1 (1997)

**Ejemplo:**

```
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
```

---

> Nota: Se puede editar esta respuesta para situaciones similares que
>   hayamos encontrado.

Comment: De un modo similar, deberíamos evitar / y \ cuando establecemos una ruta a un fichero